Why does the Central Limit Theorem fail for sums of Bernoulli random variables, and how does the Poisson distribution apply?
I am working on this question. I proved section (a) using the uniqueness of the MGF property, but for part (b), I don’t have any idea. could anyone help me for part b?
question: We mentioned that invoking the CLT to approximate the distribution
of sums of independent Bernoulli random variables using a Gaussian can be a bad idea. Let
$X_1, ..., X_n \sim B(p)$ be independent Bernoulli random variables with common mean $p = \frac{n\lambda}{n}$,
where $\lambda \in (0,1)$. For $n$ natural number, let
$$
P_n(x) = P(X_1 + ... + X_n = x).
$$
(a) Show that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} P_n(x) = e^{-\lambda} \cdot \frac{\lambda^x}{x!},
$$
which is a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$.
(b) Explain why this does not contradict the CLT and discuss the implications of the Berry–Esseen theorem.

(1) What have you tried? Have you looked at the assumptions of the CLT? Are they satisfied? (2) Did you mean $p=\lambda /n$ for the common mean?

Following @TrevorNorton, the distribution of $X_1, \ldots$ changing with $n$ is a major issue.

@TrevorNorton (1)Yes I looked at the assumptions of the CLT. it just says variance doesn't have to be infinity and it is correct for this Bernoulli distribution. (2) yes. I mean p=λ/n
for the common mean.
